# Rsync include/exclude don't work in python subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsync

I use rsync to move files from my home computer to a server. Here's the command that I use to transfer and update the directory of only files that contain a grep + glob. I execute this command from the `toplevel/` directory in the directory structure I show below.

```
 rsync -r --progress --include='**201609*/***' --exclude='*' -avzh files/ user@server.edu:/user/files
```

Here's what the file structure of the working directory on my home file looks like:

```
 - toplevel
      - items
      - files
        - 20160315
        - 20160910
          - dir1
            - really_cool_file1
        - 20160911
          - dir2
```

This works fine, and the file structure on `user@server.edu:/user/files` is the same as on my home computer.

---

I wrote a python script to do this and it doesn't work. It also transfers over the `files/20160315`, which is not what I want.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
 import os
 from subprocess import run

 os.chdir("toplevel")

 command_run = ["rsync", "-r",
           "--progress",
           "--include='**201609*/***'",
           "--exclude='*'",
           "-avzh",
           "files/", "user@server.edu:/user/files"]

 run(command_run, shell=False, check=True)
```

What's going on here? I had the same problem when `command_run` was a string, and I passed it to `subprocess.run()` with `shell=True`.

Comment: The quotes are for the shell, not rsync.

Comment: yeah, the single quotes are stripped. Try for instance `"--include=**201609*/***"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of those quotes are removed by the shell before being passed to the called process. You need to do this yourself if you call the program with the default `shell=False`. This little script will tell you what your parameters need to look like

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

And then running with your command line

```
~/tmp $ ./test.py -r --progress --include='**201609*/***' --exclude='*' -avzh files/ user@server.edu:/user/files
['./test.py', '-r', '--progress', '--include=**201609*/***', '--exclude=*', '-avzh', 'files/', 'user@server.edu:/user/files']
~/tmp $
```

Comment: stripping the single quotes from my script fixed it for me! Thanks everyone!